# Querying multiple databases using distributed web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services

I have a quick question about best practices and especially expected performance for the following scenario:

If I want to query data from multiple servers that contain schematically identital sql databases, would having each server provide a web method that a single client application can consume be an appropriate (and relatively fast) solution?

The data just needs to be consolidated on the client end, where several web methods would have to be consumed serially (or in parallel?) to provide the data to the client. Each server would also be implementing Entity Framework as an ORM.

Performance is my main concern here, would it turn out excessively slow as we start to scale up to more and more servers?

Comment: What's the reason to not do this "database" work in the database? Perhaps using something like SSIS.

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry I'm relatively new to all this. Is that where the databases mirror / copy eachother or there is some sort of 'master' database that consolidates all the others? If so, thats a possible solution but I'm curious about this option nevertheless. I have to work with limited resources for now.

Comment: SSIS is a tool that can do things like, as an example, copy five same-schema databases to one destination. It's [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not performance, is reliability. As the number of services you need to query to return a response to the client increases, the reliability decreases. Say you have 99% availability for a database (less than 4 days of total downtime for maintenance, patches and upgrades through an entire year). If you need to query 5 databases your client sees and actual availability of only 95%, almost 18 days a year your site appears down. At 10 databases the availability is 90% (35 days down) and 50 servers plummet to 60% which means your site is unusable.

This is why the driving force in this scale out scenarios is the reliability, which can be achieved only by decoupling the databases. The usual trick is to implement an asynchronous messaging buss for the databases to communicate, and have each request to the site connect only on its local shard never ever querying more than one database per request.

For a more detailed explanation how this is done at massive scale, see [this presentation how MySpace uses a SQL Server based messaging buss to achieve scalability](http://www.slideshare.net/markginnebaugh/myspace-sql-server-service-broker-oct-2009).

This SIGMOD 2009 Keynote presents in turn how Facebook achieves similar results: [Building Facebook: Performance at Massive Scale](http://hosted.mediasite.com/mediasite/Viewer/?peid=459a9f2cb92d4830b40d3e64003a50e61d), using memcached and MySQL partitioning.

Comment: Your point about reliability makes sense, I think what I am going to do is create a new database entirely that pulls data from all the others at scheduled intervals. Since the relational data needs to pass through a business logic layer I think I'll have to use web services though. Its not just straight copying of the sql data.

Answer (score 0):

If your schematically identical data is residing in different databases, then have you looked into table partitioning and storing all your data in one database? That might help.

In your current scenarios I would suggest that you fetch the data from different database servers using ORM/ADO.Net and then logically merge them in your application.

In SQL Server 2005 [there are ways](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345140%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to expose data through web service but I would not suggest that as web service itself will give you performance penalty because you are crossing application boundary.